# work with files, how to calculate Avrg

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input:txt file

iam working with file contains lot of data and i have to get some numbers after specified sentence then calc avrg of these number

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
count = 0
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

for lines in fh:
    if lines.startswith ("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        lines = float (lines [20:50])
        count = count +1
        print lines  
        print count
```

what i get from here is

```
0.8475
0.6178
0.6961
0.7565
0.7626
0.7556
0.7002
0.7615
0.7601
0.7605
0.6959
0.7606
0.7559
0.7605
0.6932
0.7558
0.6526
0.6948
0.6528
0.7002
0.7554
0.6956
0.6959
0.7556
0.9846
0.8509
0.9907
```

that loop get to lines start with that txt "X-DSPAM-Confidence:"
and strip it from 20:50 (end of it)

then get me to 2 things get the list of numbers needed and the count which will help later, now i need to sum number to calc avrg. the sum / count

how can i do that? looking for simplest way ever not a problem if i get long code

well i just improved code removed unwanted things sorry for that

print things not important but just to see what i am doing as i am a new to python

Comment: what is the first loop supposed to be doing? Also the second is doing nothing as you have exhausted the iterator

Comment: Can you show is what the line beginning with `X-DSPAM-Confidence looks like?

Comment: If @AMR has the solution that worked, pick his as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your own code just keep track of the total  and divide at the end:

```
count = 0
total = 0
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

for lines in fh:
    if lines.startswith ("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count += 1
        total += float (lines [20:50])
        print lines  
        print count

print(total/count)
```

If you need to store all the data then a list comp would be the best approach to store all the floats then sum and divide the length to get the average:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname) as f:
    all_data = [float(line[20:50]) for line in f if line.startswith ("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")]
    avg =  sum(all_data) / len(all_data)
    print(all_data)
    print(avg)
```

Comment: I think yours is correct if there is only one floating number per line. I was assuming that there was more than one, but then there would need to be some form of split. I asked OP to post what a line of the data looks like.

Comment: @AMR,  the OP is slicing a single float per line so there must only be  a single float per line

Comment: It seemed weird that the slice was from 20 to 50 for just 1 number, but I guess he did that to capture the number. If the number was the only thing after the `X-DSPAM-Confidence:`, then I would think `[20: ]` would be clearer.

Comment: I think you need to add float() to your list comp. You would be saving string values, so sum would error, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if we saw a sample of your data, but you should be able to do this:

```
sum_lines = sum(lines)
avg_lines = sum_lines / count
```

`sum()` is a built in function which will sum an iterable.
I am also wondering why you are reassigning your value to lines when you do

```
lines = float (lines [20:50])
```

I would think if those are multiple comma separated floating point numbers, you would want to assign it to a list variable like `float_list` and then `sum` using the `sum()` function.

If you do not want to save the average, you could put a third `print` that says

```
print sum(float_list) / count
```

> Updated to Reflect OP Update

Yes you definitely want to create a list. instead of `lines = float (lines [20:50])` do this:

```
float_list = []
float_list = float(line[20:50])
```

A better way to do this would be to do it with list comprehension.

```
float_list = [float(lines[20:50] for lines in fh if lines.startwith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")]
```

> Update...

I think that I misunderstood your original use of the slice [20:50] as representing multiple numbers per line.

If it is only one number, then it would be this, which is basically the answer that Padraic Cunningham posted:

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

float_list = [float(lines[20:50] for lines in fh if lines.startwith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")]

list_sum = sum(float_list)
count = len(float_list)
list_avg = list_sum / count
```

For future reference, it is helpful to post an example of your input data along with your code and desired output in your original question.

Comment: i just added more if that's gonna help :D

Comment: your method seems to be working when i looked to it :D but into my code it say iter must be iterable ! 

can you add the first method inside my code so i can see how it works?
and i changed lines >> num <<

Answer (score -1):

Depends mostly on the formatting of your numbers, are they CSV, are they on their own line etc. In any case, a general solution:

As some of the comments have pointed out, your first loop will ruin your iterator, so I combined the two loops. The if else is redundant as `if not` will work fine.

```
count = 0
sum = 0
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname,'r')
lines = fh.readlines()
fh.close()
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith ("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else:
        line = float(line)
        count = count +1
        sum += line
avg = sum/count
print avg
```